# Developing a java netbeans application that allows users to save their work

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence

Sirs,

In connection with another java netbeans project, I need to create a practice project that does the following:

1.)  allows users to enter text into a jTextArea (5 or 6 sentences).
2.)  allows users to save the entered text to their computer for future uses of the application.
3.)  allows users to load previously saved text from a file on their computer into the jTextArea.

I should add that I know how to read and write from files in general in most every language I know.  It's the part about doing it in Netbeans that I need help with.

I guess my real problem is that I don't really know any of the netbeans buzzwords or vocabulary to be able to search around for tutorials on how to do this.  I suspect this involves "persistence files" or something, but it gets fuzzy from there.

Lastly, creating a netbeans project with a jTextArea, adding functionality to buttons are all things I know how to do well -- my only problem is that I don't have a clue where to begin (or even begin searching) on allowing users to save text entered into a jTextArea on Netbeans.

I'm not asking someone to write a comprehensive tutorial for me -- I'm just wanting someone to point me to a tutorial on how to do all this in netbeans, or a quick step guide to get me started.

Thanks

the_photon

Comment: Look into reading and writing files, and the Oracle Java Tutorial's Swing section.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback -- but can anyone be a bit more specific.  I know how to read and write to files in general in most every computer programming language that I know -- What I'm looking for is a tutorial on how to do this specifically in netbeans with a jTextArea.

Comment: Then you have the exact reason why your question is being closed.     https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Attach an ActionListener or select Events->Action->ActionPerformed  on a menu option or button and save the text to a hard-coded/previously set file with this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), this.jTextArea1.getText().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Or to let the user pick the file first:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        if (chooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Files.write(chooser.getSelectedFile().toPath(), this.jTextArea1.getText().getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```